# Committing concurrent transactions only if all of them succeed

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, parallel-processing

What I want is to execute a procedure ( that will run on  Oracle 11g) concurrently, and to commit the whole operation if an only if all the concurrent transactions succeeded.

Two ways of parallel execution that I thought of were  `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` and `dbms_job.submit()`, but as I understand it, in both cases the processes created are running in their separate sessions and each process commits the changes upon termination (or in case of an error can rollback **its own** changes).

What I would like, is to start parallel processes, wait until each one of them is finished, check if they all were successful and only then commit the changes (or rollback if at least one process failed).

Is the above scenario possible? (And how can it be implemented)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am curious why this requirement came about; I would probably question whether it was really necessary if this came to me. But if you cannot question the requirement, this is how I would go about it.

```
-- We need to have a common persistent location for all of the jobs to read
CREATE TABLE test_tab
(
   job_name VARCHAR2(30),
   status   VARCHAR2(30)
)
/

-- The procedure writing to our table must be autonomous so that updates occur 
-- without committing the rest of the work
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_log
(
   i_job_name IN VARCHAR2,
   i_status   IN VARCHAR2
) IS
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
   MERGE INTO test_tab tgt
   USING dual
   ON (tgt.job_name = i_job_name)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET status = i_status
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT VALUES (i_job_name, i_status);
   COMMIT;
END test_log;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc(i_job_name IN VARCHAR2) IS
   l_complete_cnt INTEGER;
   l_error_cnt    INTEGER;
   l_waiting      BOOLEAN := TRUE;
BEGIN
   -- !!! Your code here !!!

   /* -- Uncomment this block to prove the rollback scenario.
   IF i_job_name LIKE '%8' THEN
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Throwing an error to prove rollback.');
   END IF;*/

   test_log(i_job_name, 'COMPLETE');

   WHILE l_waiting LOOP
      SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ('COMPLETE', 'COMMITTED') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ERROR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        INTO l_complete_cnt
            ,l_error_cnt
        FROM test_tab
       WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(job_name, 'TEST_JOB_\d');

      IF l_complete_cnt = 8 THEN
         COMMIT;
         test_log(i_job_name, 'COMMITTED');
         l_waiting := FALSE;
      ELSIF l_error_cnt > 0 THEN
         ROLLBACK;
         test_log(i_job_name, 'ROLLBACK');
         l_waiting := FALSE;
      ELSE
         dbms_lock.sleep(seconds => 5);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      test_log(i_job_name, 'ERROR');
      RAISE;
END;
/

-- Begin test section
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..8 LOOP
      dbms_scheduler.create_job('TEST_JOB_'||i
                               ,'PLSQL_BLOCK'
                               ,'BEGIN test_proc(''TEST_JOB_'||i||'''); END;'
                               ,start_date => SYSDATE
                               ,enabled => TRUE);
   END LOOP;
END;
/

SELECT * FROM test_tab;
TRUNCATE TABLE test_tab; --the table should be cleared between tests
```

Comment: If you're curious about the *"why"* you can look [at the OP's history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5532778/plirkee): their questions from the last week or so all seem related to this one.

Comment: @APC I had the impression that the above should work. But here comes your comment... ;-/  As I see it - each job on success puts a record of 'complete' in the table . if everybody have successfully completed their tasks  then `l_complete_cnt` becomes `8` and everybody commits (still `l_complete_cnt` remains `8`) , on the other hand if there is at least one error everybody `rolls back` - what did I miss?

Comment: Doh,! Missed the call to `dbms_lock.sleep()`. Yes, this should work. The snag is that you will need to monitor the threads somehow and manually kill the remaining sessions if one of them dies. Or you can automate it, but you're starting to build a lot of framework code. Obviously worth it if this will be a regular task.

Comment: This works as long as your Processes dont involve unique constraint violations. If two jobs run into updating a table which goes on to unique contraint this goes into infinite lock. How to solve that scenario?